# Playing Audio in HTML

Tags: html, audio, playback

I want to play a mp3 audio file in HTML. I don't want to display the whole player with controls like Volume etc.
I just need a play/pause button, Designed by me, not the core design of some player, like yahoo player, or google one.

For example the audio will be autoplay. When a button (probably an image) is clicked it will pause, and when that image is clicked again, the audio will play again.

There are quite few examples here : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp

Can I control any of them to play/stop from JS code ?

Comment: Unfortunately, implementing this yourself is a bit of a nightmare. I recommend using a plug-in for this--there simply is no official Javascript API for audio.

Comment: flash would be the only alternative for this

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the html5 [audio tag](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-audio-element). You can specify your own controls for playback.

```
<audio preload="auto" autobuffer> 
  <source src="elvis.mp3" />
  <source src="elvis.wav" /> <!-- fallback if no mp3 support in browser -->
</audio>
```

This is a jQuery solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/QPW27/109/

This is what your non-jQuery solution would look like.

```
var foo = document.getElementById('player');
foo.pause();  //just bind play/pause to some onclick events on your page
foo.play();
```

Different browsers support different audio formats. You can specify fallback audio versions though. This website has a nice [chart of browser support](http://www.scirra.com/blog/44/on-html5-audio-formats-aac-and-ogg) as of July 2011.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully, in a few years, the [HTML5 audio API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-audio-element) will be supported accross more browsers, but currently, playing sounds requires either a lot of browser-specific hacks to get things working, or reliance on a browser plugin like flash.

In the meantime, I reccomend using [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/). It's fairly easy to work with and will involve much less headache than doing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

[Audio.js](http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/) looks like it has the player styling features you're looking for, with a graceful degradation to Flash if the browser doesn't support the new audio API.

Answer (score 0):

You can play audio by using embed tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p><a href="horse.mp3">Play mp3</a></p>
<p><a href="liar.wav">Play wav</a></p>

<script src="http://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```