# How to provide src attribute in html to play audio stored computer?

Tags: html

I want to play the audio in browser using html; and how to play the audio/video that is stored in our computer/laptop in html

I have tried below code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio controls>
  <source src="C:\Users\abc\Desktop\song.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="C:\Users\abc\Desktop\song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

This is not working...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playing Audio in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641355/playing-audio-in-html)

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code,may be your browser is not supporting or make sure the file is present

Comment: Browsers tend to be very strict about allowing access to local computer's resources. Where do you have that html file? If it's on a server somewhere, you're simply stuck. If the browsers allowed this, it could potentially be used to infringe on users privacy, or be a security hole of some other kind.

Answer (score 1):

There many different tags you can use to play audio using HTML for example you could use the `<object>` tag:

```
<object height="50" width="100" data="Example.mp3"></object>
```

Or the `<embed>` tag:

```
<embed height="50" width="100" src="Example.mp3">
```

But the best solution is to use these lines of code:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="example.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="example.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <embed height="50" width="100" src="Example.mp3">
</audio>
```

Your code is also correct but your browser may not be supporting.
Thanks for listening and if you need more information please visit www.w3schools.com