# How I can put data in the html?

Tags: php, html

I will create a website in that website admin upload some audio files in the server everything is work perfect but I was uploaded a PHP file in that file I will fetch all the data (Name of file and URL of that file) from the database but I don't know how I can put that data into my HTML code. In HTML when the user clicks the name then URL should load and play music.

```
<?php
 define('DB_HOST','localhost');
 define('DB_USERNAME','Root');
 define('DB_PASSWORD','');
 define('DB_NAME','audiofiles');

 //connecting to the db
 $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or 
 die("Unable to connect");

 //sql query 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM audio";

//getting result on execution the sql query
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//response array
$response = array();

$response['audio'] = array();

//traversing through all the rows

 while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 $temp = array();
 $temp['id'] = $row['id'];
 $temp['name'] = $row['name'];
 $temp['url'] = $row['url'];
 array_push($response['audio'],$temp);
 }
```

This is my PHP of fetching audio files from the database. I want some help to display that audio file in the HTML page and also play that files. I want to do that PHP file should grab that name and link of the audio file which will work perfectly now I want HTML to embed name and the link as the src.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Playing Audio in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641355/playing-audio-in-html).

Comment: How I can add that name and link in HTML Page

Comment: **Reminder**: do not use DB user `root` for website. Create a new DB user instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `<audio>` HTML tag inside `while()` loop like below:-

```
while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>
    <?php echo $row['name'];?> : <audio controls><source src="<?php echo $row['url'];?>"></audio><br>
<?php }?>
```

So full code needs to be:-

```
<?php
 define('DB_HOST','localhost');
 define('DB_USERNAME','Root');
 define('DB_PASSWORD','');
 define('DB_NAME','audiofiles');

 //connecting to the db
 $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or 
 die("Unable to connect");

 //sql query 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM audio";

//getting result on execution the sql query
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//traversing through all the rows

while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>
    <?php echo $row['name'];?> : <audio controls><source src="<?php echo $row['url'];?>"></audio><br>
<?php }?>
```